# Using streams in Node.js to buffer HTTP communications

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, stream, pipe

I'm trying to use streams in Node.js to basically build a running buffer of HTTP data until some processing is done, but I'm struggling with the specifics of streams. Some pseudocode will probably help:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    // Create a buffer stream to hold data generated by the asynchronous process
    // to be piped to the response after headers and other obvious response data
    var buffer = new http.ServerResponse();

    // Start the computation of the full response as soon as possible, passing
    // in the buffer stream to hold returned data until headers are written
    beginAsyncProcess(request, buffer);

    // Send headers and other static data while waiting for the full response
    // to be generated by 'beginAsyncProcess'
    sendObviousData(response, function() {

        // Once obvious data is written (unfortunately HTTP and Node.js have
        // certain requirements for the order data must be written in) then pipe
        // the stream with the data from 'beginAsyncProcess' into the response
        buffer.pipe(response);
    });
});
```

Most of this is almost legitimate code, but it doesn't work. The basic issue is figuring out a way to take advantage of the asynchronous nature of Node.js when there are certain order requirements associated with HTTP requests, namely that headers must always be written first.

While I would definitely appreciate any answers with little hacks to get around the order problem without directly addressing streams, I wanted to use the opportunity to get to know them better. There are plenty of similar situations, but this scenario is more to open the can of worms than anything else.

Comment: In this case your actual code would be better than a pseudo code :)

Comment: @Urahara That's basically it, sendObviousData sends headers, stylesheets, etc. These are static. The actual content is generated by beginAsyncProcess, and takes time to generate. The idea is to send the headers, stylesheets, etc. while waiting for the content to be generated, and then send that when it's ready. The problem is that there's always the chance that the content will outrun the headers and cause an error that would be really annoying to catch and try to handle. I'm trying to take advantage of asynchronous code while avoiding race conditions.

Comment: looks to me you can simply sendObviousData() before you even start beginAsyncProcess(), but it's hard to tell with make-believe parts... i do this a lot; write the headers right away then use an async process to pipe into response.end(). works well unless you want to change headers based on the slow async response.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist Have you heard of `marko` https://github.com/raptorjs/marko ? this allows you to pipe the incoming html template and inject data asynchronously, while writting to the response buffer.

Comment: @dandavis If I called sendObviousData before beginAsyncProcess, asynchronously, beginAsyncProcess could start generating body data before sendObviousData is done with the headers, preventing the rest of the headers from being sent. If I call sendObviousData before beginAsyncProcess synchronously, the whole thing's synchronous and slow. The part I'm trying to figure out is the buffer, which you'll notice doesn't do what it's supposed to.

Comment: @Urahara, it seems that `marko` is first and foremost a templating engine, and considering I already have the content covered, it would be way too heavy to use just for injecting http data. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: ok, well i don't know what sendObviousData() does, but you can call, for example (from slightly old but actual production code), `res.writeHead( 200, CLIENT.headers ); fs.createReadStream("."+CLIENT.finalURL, {'bufferSize': 4 * 1024 }).pipe(res);` without worrying about racing the headers...

Comment: @dandavis Let's try to put it in an correct answer so that other might use it.

Comment: @Urahara: i don't even know if it's an answer, but if we get there, i'll upgrade. the part i'm confused about is what's causing the race. without seeing the problem code, i can't tell. JS's single-thread nature means that from the same script, the pipe() call cannot come before the writeHead() call, so i'm not sure what the actual real-world issue is without seeing the actual broken code.

Comment: @dandavis No filesystem stuff, `sendObviousData` sends header data, which should run in parallel with `beginAsyncProcess`. The problem I'm trying to solve is letting `beginAsyncProcess` run and generate content without risking it pushing data to the stream before `sendObviousData` is done. Under normal conditions, considering how long it should take `beginAsyncProcess` to generate its data, it shouldn't outrun `sendObviousData`, but it's a possibility that has to be handled somehow. That's why I'm trying to buffer the output of `beginAsyncProcess`.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist: from what you describe in the question and comments, i don't think it's a possibility.

Comment: @dandavis I find it very hard to believe that given the amount of popularity Node.js has earned from it's _incredible_ stream system, there's no way of buffering a writable stream.

Comment: we use streams so that we don't have to buffer. all i'm saying is that i've been using node for about 5 years and i've never seen a writeHead() call interrupted. maybe it's because headers are small, maybe writeHead() is sync, or maybe createServer does internal buffering, but at the end of the day, it's no problem. if you could post some code that contradicts my observations, i would be enlightened and most appreciative. i also only used the _fs_ as an example of an async stream, in this case pipe()ing a readable to a writable.

Comment: @dandavis Better question then, if by some odd feat of statistics the body data from `beginAsyncProcess` _does_ interrupt the headers from `sendObviousData`, how would I catch that and react? I'm assuming there's no way to clear the slate and start over once data has been sent.

Comment: 2 thoughts: 1. node will catch it for you: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L131 2. it appears writeHead() is all sync, so that can't happen. https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js

Comment: @dandavis So as long as the headers are written all at once with `response.writeHead`, and this just _starts_ before `beginAsyncProcess`, it doesn't really matter about race conditions, because the headers will always be synchronous, and therefore completed before `beginAsyncProcess` is called, and other data like stylesheets really don't matter much when it comes to race conditions. Nice. I'd say it's answer-ready.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a use of callbacks and streams in Node.js and `.pause()` / `.resume()` stream functions:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    // Handle the request first, then..

    var body = new Stream(); // <-- you can implement stream.Duplex for read / write operations
        body.on('open', function(){
            body.pause();
            // API generate data
            // body.write( generated data ) <-- write to the stream
            body.resume();
        });

    var firstPartOfThePage = getHTMLSomeHow();

    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    response.write(firstPartOfThePage, function(){ // <-- callback after sending first part, our body already being processed
        body.pipe( response ); // <-- This should fire after being resumed
        body.on('end', function(){
            response.end(); // <-- end the response
        });
    });
});
```

Check this: http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-31-nodejs-duplex-streams.html for costum duplex stream creation.

**Note: it's still a pseudo code**

Comment: The process isn't bad, but as I wrote in the question (or rather as I _didn't_ write in the question) there was never any use of the filesystem. All of the data is computed using API's, none of which conform to the streams consumption pattern in Node.js.

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you comment on that, is it useful to you?

Comment: I'd say it's definitely worth keeping. As long as it works (I haven't yet tested it) it could come in handy to someone in the future.

Comment: Then +1, I'm trying to gain some respect up in here ;)